# Proving $d$ is a metric of a power set

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $E$ be a ﬁnite set. For every pair of subsets $A,\ B$ of $E$, deﬁne
$d(A, B)$ as the number of elements $AΔB$,
where $AΔB$ denotes the symmetric differencia of $A$ and $B$ deﬁned by $(A\setminus B)\cup (B \setminus A)$. Prove that
$d$ is a metric on $P(E)$, the power set of $E$, i.e., the set of all subsets of $E$, including the empty set
and $E$.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know the axioms of a metric? If so, were you able to make process in showing any of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn’t want to step on walcher’s hints, but it’s been a couple of days now, so I thought that I’d point out a slightly different way of looking at the space. Instead of looking at the subsets of $E$, you can look at their [indicator functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function); then $d(A,C)$ is simply $|\{e\in E:\chi_A(e)\ne\chi_C(e)\}|$. In other words, it’s the number of values of $\chi_A$ that you have to change in order to transform $\chi_A$ into $\chi_C$. This lets you get at the triangle inequality in a fairly nice way. I want to show that $d(A,C)\le d(A,B)+d(B,C)$.

Suppose that I first change $d(A,B)$ values of $\chi_A$ to transform it into $\chi_B$, and then change $d(B,C)$ values of $\chi_B$ to transform it into $\chi_C$.

1. Some values I’ve not changed at all; those are for points of $E$ on which $\chi_A,\chi_B$, and $\chi_C$ all agree. These contribute nothing to $d(A,B),d(B,C)$, or $d(A,C)$.
2. Some I’ve changed twice, either from $0$ to $1$ to $0$, or from $1$ to $0$ to $1$; those are for points of $E$ on which $A$ and $C$ agree with each other and disagree with $A$. These contribute to $d(A,B)$ and to $d(B,C)$ but not to $d(A,C)$.
3. And some I’ve changed once; these are for points of $E$ on which $A$ and $C$ disagree, and $B$ agrees with one of them. Each of these contributes to $d(A,C)$ and to exactly one of $d(A,B)$ and $d(B,C)$.

The points of $E$ counted in (1) and (3) contribute identically to $d(A,B)+d(B,C)$ and $d(A,C)$, while those counted in (2) contribute only to $d(A,B)+d(B,C)$.

By the way, there’s no need for the underlying set $E$ to be finite, so long as you limit yourself to the set of *finite* subets of $E$: this still gives you a metric.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You need to check

(1.) $d(A,B)=0 \Longleftrightarrow A=B$
(2.) $d(A,B)=d(B,A)$
(3.) $d(A,B)+d(B,C)\ge d(A,C)$

For (1.) note that $A\setminus B=\emptyset\Longleftrightarrow A\subseteq B$.
For (2.) note that $A\triangle B=B\triangle A$.
For (3.) try to prove $A\triangle C\subseteq (A\triangle B) \cup (B\triangle C)$.

Comment: Ahh ok, first two axioms I think I got down. Triangle inequality seems to be a bit more tricky. I'll struggle with it for a bit. Thanks for the hint!