# Proving that a metric space of a power set is complete

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I used [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482552/proving-d-is-a-metric-of-a-power-set) to understand how $d$ is the metric space of the power set of $\Bbb N$.  Now I want to show that the metric space $(P(\Bbb N, d)$ is complete, in other words every Cauchy sequence in $P(\Bbb N)$ is convergent.  Note that $P(\Bbb N)$ denotes the power set of $\Bbb N$.  In my case, $d(A,B) = \sum_{i\in AΔB}2^{-i}$.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Define $A:= \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} \bigcap_{m \geq n} A_m$. This is the set of all $i\in \Bbb N$ which lie in all but finitely many of the sets $A_n$.

Choose an arbitrary $N \in \Bbb N$. Now, choose $M \in \Bbb N$ such that $m,n \geq M$ implies that $d(A_n,A_m)<2^{-N}$. This means that $d(A_m,A_M)<2^{-N}$ for all $m \geq M$, and thus $A_m \cap \{1,...,N\} = A_M \cap \{1,...,N\}$ for all $m \geq M$, which must therefore be the same as $A \cap \{1,...,N\}$. Hence $d(A,A_m)<2^{-N}$ whenever $m \geq M$, so that $A_m \to A$.

Comment: How do we conclude that $A_m \cap \{1,...,N\}=A_M \cap \{1,...,N\} = A \cap \{1,...,N\}$ ?

Comment: Look at the definition of the metric $d$. What can you say about $A$ and $B$ if $d(A,B)<2^{-N}$.